# Stuck on a question involving Taylors Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have a function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\Re$ and im told that it satisfies the following:

i) $f$ and $f'$ are continous on $[0,1]$ and $f''$ exists on $(0,1)$

ii)$f'(0)=f'(1)=0$

iii)$|f''(x)|\le1 $ $\forall x\in [0,1]$

I am told to show that $ |f(1/2) − f(0)| \le1/8$  which I have done.
Next I am told to show that $ |f(1) − f(0)| \le1/4$ but I can only get as far as showing that it is less than $1/2$ not $1/4$, any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in [0,1]$ and using mean value theorem,
$$|f'(x)|=|f'(x)-f'(0)|=|f''(\xi_x)x|\leqslant |x|=x.$$
Similarly, $|f'(x)|=|f'(1)-f'(x)|=|f''(\psi_x)(1-x)|\leqslant |1-x|=1-x.$
Now we have 
$$|f(1)-f(0)|=\Big|\int_0^1 f'(x)dx\Big| \leqslant \int_0^{1/2} |f'(x)|dx + \int_{1/2}^{1} |f'(x)|dx$$$$\leqslant \int_0^{1/2}x dx + \int_{1/2}^1 (1-x)dx =\frac{1}{4}.$$

Comment: sorry, how did you get the 2nd equalities in the first two lines?

Comment: Can you write again the inequality here?

Comment: $|f'(x)-f'(0)|=|f''(\xi_x)x|$ and
$|f'(x)|=|f'(1)-f'(x)|=|f''(\psi_x)(1-x)|$, also do the $\xi_x$ and $\psi_x$ just represent a value in $[0,1]$?

Comment: This is from mean value theorem.

Comment: Of course, thank you so much